# Can't pull first $key from CSV using foreach

Tags: php, foreach, fgetcsv

I am trying to pull data out of a foreach loop but I'm running into a strange phenomenon that I haven't encountered yet.

The first row of the CSV looks like this:

```
Part Number,Description,List Price
```

Then Data so on and so forth.

What I have:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);
if (($openItems = fopen($uploadFile, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
   foreach (fgetcsv($openItems) as $key => $value) {
        $value = preg_replace('/\h+/', '', strtolower($value));
        echo $value;
        echo ' = ' . $key . " ";
        switch ($value) {
            case "partnumber":
                $pn = $key;
                break;
            case "description":
                $des = $key;
                break;
            case "listprice":
                $lp = $key;
                break;
        }
    }
    print_r("\npn: " . $pn . " des: " . $des . " lp: " . $lp);
}
```

Print:

```
partnumber = 0 description = 1 listprice = 2 
pn:  des: 1 lp: 2
```

As you can see the first column is falsey so it is not assigned the proper value.

Alternative Print:

```
test = 0 partnumber = 1 description = 2 listprice = 3 
pn: 1 des: 2 lp: 3
```

Type check:

```
echo "I'm of Type ". gettype($value) . ". ";
```

returns:

```
partnumber = 0 I'm of Type string. description = 1 I'm of Type string. listprice = 2 I'm of Type string.
```

Side Note:

```
case "partnumber":
    $pn = $key;
    break;
```

is never accessed

```
case "partnumber":
    $pn = $key;
    echo "I Worked!";
    break;
```

This returns without any result.

Any Suggestions?

This Scenario is thanks to @azjezz

```
$csv = [];
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);
if (($openItems = fopen($uploadFile, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    foreach (fgetcsv($openItems) as $key => $value) {
        $value = preg_replace('/\h+/', '', strtolower($value));
        $csv[$value] = (Int) $key;
        echo $value;
        echo ' = ' . $key . " ";
        switch ($csv[$value]) {
            case "partnumber":
                $pn = $key;
                break;
            case "description":
                $des = $key;
                break;
            case "listprice":
                $lp = $key;
                break;
        }
    }
    print_r("\npn: " . $pn . " des: " . $des . " lp: " . $lp);
}
```

Results in:

```
partnumber = 0 description = 1 listprice = 2 
pn: 0 des:  lp:
```

Another weird scinario:

```
    switch ((int) $value) {
        case "partnumber":
            $pn = $key;
            break;
        case "description":
            $des = $key;
            break;
        case "listprice":
            $lp = $key;
            break;
    }
```

Returns:

```
partnumber = 0 description = 1 listprice = 2 
pn: 2 des:  lp:
```

Comment: 17 questions asked, no answers accepted. You need to work on that.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way?  This is making reading a CSV file soo complicated it may put off any answers.

Comment: @NigelRen In this manner I can assign the values to each column as that column no matter how many columns there are or what order they are in. That way if the CSV was like List Price,Description,Part Number. Then I would still be able to identify and assign the value accordingly to a database or file or where ever I'm storing or manipulating it.

Comment: @AlexHowansky There I worked on it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't mind me proposing an alternative method to the one your following.

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);
if (($openItems = fopen($uploadFile, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    // Read the header line with the field names in it
    $keyLine = fgets($openItems);
    $keyLine = preg_replace('/\h+/', '', strtolower($keyLine));
    // Convert the line into an array of field names
    $keys = str_getcsv($keyLine);
    // While you have some more data in the file...
    while ( $data = fgetcsv($openItems)) {
        $csv = [];
        $csv['pn'] = $data[array_search('partnumber', $keys )];
        $csv['lp'] = $data[array_search('listprice', $keys )];
        $csv['des'] = $data[array_search('description', $keys )];
        print_r($csv);
    }
    fclose($openItems);
}
```

This would hopefully be simpler and more concise than your trying to get working. The main loop just reads a line in and then checks where any particular element is held in the line (could be better to assign this to an stored value rather than using `array_search` each time).

One thing which could be improved on is that it assumes that each field is present.  You could add extra logic to say if the description field isn't present then don't try and fetch a value for it.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran:

```
var_dump($value);
```

I got:

```
string(13) "partnumber"
string(11) "description"
string(9) "listprice"
```

But partnumber has 10 characters in it so that means hidden characters are getting through. so I changed my regular expression to this:

```
$value = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/', '', strtolower($value)));
```